# Can't access socket.io

Tags: node.js, javascript, websocket

this might be a bit of a silly question but it's something that i've been struggling to find the answer to and for some reason it doesn't seem to be evident from the tutorials and websites i have been reading, so maybe it's something that is assumed that i'm really missing.

So anyway, i installed `node.js` and then used the command `npm install socket.io`. it them proceeds to download and install a bunch of files, i don't see any error with this process in the command line.

So now i've tried to access socket.io like this:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Like it shows on the socket.io website, however i get an error saying the file isn't found..... my first guess is that the installation of node.js and stocket.io are both on the local machine (program files) and not in the htdocs.

I have tested this one two platforms, first was my localhost which is Windows 7 running XAMPP on it, and i installed node.js and stocket.io globally (Program files). Second was my Windows server that uses IIS still get the error.

So my question is, how do i reference the stocket.io API and start using it based on the installations i have?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`npm isntall socket.io` installs Socket.IO in a local `node_modules` folder so that the library is *accessible* to you in your own Node.js applications. You still need to create (and run) a Node.js application that loads up the module and sets up an HTTP server that uses the module; the examples under [How to use](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io#how-to-use) in the project readme is a good starting point, although preexisting knowledge of Node.js will be helpful. You might check out [Node.js Tutorial with Socket.IO](http://www.danielnill.com/blog/nodejs-tutorial-with-socketio/) if you're looking for additional information.